# react router dom history.replace is not re-render component if same URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have created component where on text box keydown I am redirecting as below

```
const Search = (props) => {

  const searchKeyDown = (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'Enter'){
      if(e.target.value){
        props.history.replace(`/search/${e.target.value}`)
      } else {
        alert('Search cannot be empty')
      }
    }
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      Search <input type='text' placeholder='Search...' onKeyDown={(e) => {searchKeyDown(e)}}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default withRouter(Search)
```

But my component will not re-render if you change text in textbox below is my code. I have useEffect to detect state change but not working. Can somebody help me

My full stackbliz is https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-k71agk?file=index.tsx

```
const SearchData = (props:any) =>{
  const searchText = props.match.params.searchText
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useState(null)

  useEffect(()=>{
    setSearchParams(searchText)
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(searchParams !== null) console.log(searchParams)
  },[searchParams])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {searchParams}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your searchText to dependency array in useEffect:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setSearchParams(searchText)
},[searchText])
```

And component will re-rendered after any change of searchText.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Works in stackbliz. Will check in my real project

Comment: Ok looks like render works but when I call function it is showing me last content not new what can be reason. I have updated my stackbliz

Comment: It seems that your stackbliz is not available now.

Comment: stackbliz is available. Any how my issue is resolved by your suggestion